# I would like to know why my code works in one setup but not the other

Tags: python, while-loop

So im making a simple code that shows all events:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 600
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))


run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break
            
pygame.quit()
```

And quit doesnt work. I know i should put it as run = False since the code is set to run while run = True, but im wondering why break wont work the same way. After all, doesn't break also mean that the loop breaks?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You put the `break` statement inside of the for loop so Python only stops the for loop but not the while loop. `break` only stops the one loop it's in, it doesn't stop all loops.

Like the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) say:

> The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the innermost enclosing for or while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the flag run to False in order to escape the while loop:

```py
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run=False
            break
```

Comment: Not the question